# How to shorten signature display in echo area?

Tags: lsp-mode

Currently, the signature of the current function the pointer is on is shown as follows:

[image]

as you can see, the signature is so large that it overflows the echo area. I was wondering if there could be a way to shorter to something like this:

```
1/1 | FunctionName(..., current_arg type, ...) (return_type_n, return_type_m)
```

in other words, the signature from the screenshot shows as:

```
1/1 | CreateSubscription(..., identificacion_tipo model.IdentificacionTipo, ...) (*service.Subscription, error)
```

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here that points to an existing easy way to take care of this, consider filing an enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string displayed by `lsp-mode` is not generated by `lsp-mode` but by the server. If you want to achieve that open a feature request against the server that you are using.

Comment: I would think that a language server would neither know nor care how that text is displayed?  I was imagining this was eldoc rather than lsp, but either way Emacs knows the width of the window and could constrain the display to a single line (perhaps more likely by a simple truncation at the end than the kind of "intelligent" hiding of particular substrings indicated in the question).

Comment: They control the amount and the format of the text to be shown. Some of them have settings like that for onHover info. 

Truncating can be implemented on client-side. If OP is fine with that, he can open feature request in lsp-mode repo.

Comment: @IvanDimitrovYonchovski I've decided to open a feature request https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/2269